# How to combine two RegEx

Tags: regex

I've requirement like below

```
1234 1234567890 1234 (or 1234-1234567890-1234)
     1234567890 1234 (or 1234567890-1234)
```

Below are my ReqEx

```
(\d{4})[ -]?(\d{10})[ -]?(\d{4})
            (\d{10})[ -]?(\d{4})
```

Above expressions are works fine.

```
Regex validate = new Regex(@"(\d{4})[ -]?(\d{10})[ -]?(\d{4})");
Console.WriteLine(validate.Replace("123412345678901234", "$1-$2-$3"));
O/P: 1234-1234567890-1234

Regex validate = new Regex(@"(\d{10})[ -]?(\d{4})");
Console.WriteLine(validate.Replace("12341234567890", "$1-$2"));
O/P: 1234-1234567890
```

However, How can i combine above 2 RegEx into single one.

I've tried with "`(?:(\d{4})[ -])?(\d{10})[ -]?(\d{4})`" and is not working.

Comment: Have a look at this [demo](http://rextester.com/DWRS38510).  I used an alternation and basically got it working.  If you really want to use one pattern, then you will probably have to deal with the fact that each capture group is going to have a fixed number, and they are not all the same.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I'll use 2 patterns for now as i didn't get working combined one. Thanks

Comment: You can use one pattern, but I think you would have to handle the capture groups separately.  And it probably would not work with a one-liner as you had it.

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: @PrasadKanaparthi:  A note: you cannot get a `1234-1234567890` result when applying `@"(\d{10})[ -]?(\d{4})"` regex with `"$1-$2"` replacement against `"12341234567890"` string. You are bound to get [`1234123456-7890`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5cd%7b10%7d%29%5b+-%5d%3f%28%5cd%7b4%7d%29&i=12341234567890&r=%241-%242).

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to achieve in C#, just use an optional non-capturing group and then, inside a match evaluator, check if the capturing group inside that one matched.

```
@"(?:(\d{4})[ -]?)?(\d{10})[ -]?(\d{4})");
  ^^^            ^^
```

I have a feeling that you also want to only match a string that only contains 1 phone number. If so, add `\A` at the start and `\z` at the end to require a full string match.

See [this C# demo](http://ideone.com/cYSk1a):

```
var vals = new List<string> {"123412345678901234", "12341234567890"};
var validate = new Regex(@"\A(?:(\d{4})[ -]?)?(\d{10})[ -]?(\d{4})\z");
foreach (var val in vals) {
    Console.WriteLine(validate.Replace(val, m =>
        m.Groups[1].Success ? $"{m.Groups[1].Value}-{m.Groups[2].Value}-{m.Groups[3].Value}" : 
        $"{m.Groups[2].Value}-{m.Groups[3].Value}")
    ); // => 1234-1234567890-1234, 1234-1234567890
}
```

NOTE: if you compile the regex object with `RegexOptions.RightToLeft` option, you will get `1234123456-7890` for the second input.

Comment: @PrasadKanaparthi: Note I just combined the patterns into one, but did not adjust the pattern to output `1234-1234567890` for `12341234567890`. Perhaps, you just can add a `RegexOptions.RightToLeft` modifier ([`new Regex(@"\A(?:(\d{4})[ -]?)?(\d{10})[ -]?(\d{4})\z", RegexOptions.RightToLeft)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5cd%7b10%7d%29%5b+-%5d%3f%28%5cd%7b4%7d%29&i=12341234567890&r=%241-%242&o=r&s=14)), but probably that was just a typo on your part.